# Handle multiple receiving bank accounts, customers can transfer money to pointing each account

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js, plaid

I need to handle multiple receiving bank accounts in my application. Additionally, customers should have a way to transfer money, pointing to a specific bank account. Can I achieve this using Plaid?

How to implement this? Is there any example resources in Plaid?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Plaid does provide APIs that can be used for moving money in this way, such as [Transfer](https://plaid.com/docs/transfer/) and [Auth](https://plaid.com/docs/auth/).